# raw folder not showing in android studio 2.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, video

I created a raw folder and placed a video file in that folder.

However it does show in Android Studio. It does shows for one split second or two when I start my activity up again. But then, once the gradle file is done being built, it disappears.

Comment: did a code clean up got this

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\Karanvir\AndroidStudioProjects\Vids\app\src\main\res\RAW\ss.mp4:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: Your folder name must be `raw` instead of `RAW`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "raw" folder must be writen in lowercase like this, i belive that this is your problem.
[image]